# twisted: difference between `defer.execute` and `threads.deferToThread`

Tags: python, multithreading, twisted, deferred-execution

What is the difference between `defer.execute()` and `threads.deferToThread()` in twisted? Both take the same arguments - a function, and parameters to call it with - and return a deferred which will be fired with the result of calling the function.

The `threads` version explicitly states that it will be run in a thread. However, if the `defer` version doesn't, then what would ever be the point of calling it? Code that runs in the reactor should never block, so any function it calls would have to not block. At that point, you could just do `defer.succeed(f(*args, **kwargs))` instead of `defer.execute(f, args, kwargs)` with the same results.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

defer.execute does indeed execute the function in a blocking manner, in the same thread and you are correct in that `defer.execute(f, args, kwargs)` does the same as `defer.succeed(f(*args, **kwargs))` **except** that `defer.execute` will return a callback that has had the errback fired if function **f** throws an exception.  Meanwhile, in your defer.succeed example, if the function threw an exception, it would propagate outwards, which may not be desired.

For ease of understanding, I'll just paste the source of defer.execute here:

```
def execute(callable, *args, **kw):
    """Create a deferred from a callable and arguments.

    Call the given function with the given arguments.  Return a deferred which
    has been fired with its callback as the result of that invocation or its
    errback with a Failure for the exception thrown.
    """
    try:
        result = callable(*args, **kw)
    except:
        return fail()
    else:
        return succeed(result)
```

In other words, `defer.execute` is just a shortcut to take a blocking function's result as a deferred which you can then add callbacks/errbacks to. The callbacks will be fired with normal chaining semantics.  It seems a bit crazy, but Deferreds can 'fire' before you add callbacks and the callbacks will still be called.

---

So to answer your question, *why is this useful*? Well, `defer.execute` is useful both for testing / mocking as well as simply integrating an async api with synchronous code.

Also useful is `defer.maybeDeferred` which calls the function and then if the function already returns a deferred simply returns it, else functions similar to `defer.execute`. This is useful for when you write an API which expects a callable that when called gives you a deferred, and you want to be able to accept normal blocking functions as well.

For example, say you had an application which fetched pages and did things with it. And, for some reason, you needed to run this in a synchronous fashion for a specific use case, like in a single-shot crontab script, or in response to a request in a WSGI application, but still keep the same codebase. If your code looked like this, it could be done:

```
from twisted.internet import defer
from twisted.web.client import getPage

def process_feed(url, getter=getPage):
    d = defer.maybeDeferred(getter, url)
    d.addCallback(_process_feed)

def _process_feed(result):
    pass # do something with result here
```

To run this in a synchronous context, without the reactor, you could just pass an alternate getter function, like so:

```
from urllib2 import urlopen

def synchronous_getter(url):
    resp = urlopen(url)
    result = resp.read()
    resp.close()
    return result
```