# Twisted deferred generation

Tags: python, twisted, deferred

While looking at some source code I found the following code:

`defer.execute(callable, args)`

I have tried to replace some of my calls that I don't really like

`task.deferLater(reactor, 0, callable, args)`

with this `execute` function, but it behaves differently, it doesn't accept chaining deferred, while `deferLater` accept a callable that can return a deferred.

Can someone explain me what are the main differences between thoses 2 methods ?

It feels somehow hacky to run a deferred by scheduling it for 0 seconds in the future, I wish to find some better way to achieve this if possible

Comment: This thread might help a bit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3686608/twisted-difference-between-defer-execute-and-threads-defertothread. Personally I've never had to use `defer.execute`.

Comment: That was a nice answer, mind making it an answer so I can accept yours ?